# Getting the total of all rows but excluding certain columns Rstudio

Tags: r, dplyr

I need to get the total of each row within my table however I want to exclude certain columns as these contain numeric data such as plot numbers or treatments that I don't want to be counted.

I have tried using mutate and rowsums for this but it doesn't seem to work and I get this error:

Error in UseMethod("mutate") :
no applicable method for 'mutate' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')"

```
    mutate(total=rowSums(select(Flower,-Survey, -Date, -Recorder, -Site, -Block, -Plot, -Treatment)))
```

Following a comment here is my updated code:

```
    df<-  mutate(total = rowSums(select(Flower, !c(Ranunculus.repens, Ranunculus.acris, Ranunculus.ficaria, Trifolium.repens, Geranium.molle, Cardamine.flexuosa, Bellis.perennis, Taraxacum.officinalis, Lamium.purpureum, Glechoma.hederacea, Cardamine.pratensis, Medicago.lupulina, Medicago.arabica, Cerastium.fontanum, Prunella.vulgaris, Sonchus.arvensis, Veronica.persica, Veronica.chamaedrys, Viola.riviniana)), na.rm = TRUE))
```

I am now getting an error message saying that X must be numeric however after checking all of the columns entered are numeric.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the first argument of `mutate` has to be a dataframe while you try to apply mutate on `total` which is a `numeric`. To make your code work you have to do:

```
library(dplyr)

mutate(Flower, total=rowSums(select(Flower,-Survey, -Date, -Recorder, -Site, -Block, -Plot, -Treatment)))
```

Using `mtcars` as example data:

```r
library(dplyr)

mtcars |> 
  mutate(total = rowSums(select(mtcars, !c(hp, mpg, disp, drat, wt, qsec))))
#>                      mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb total
#> Mazda RX4           21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4    15
#> Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4    15
#> Datsun 710          22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1    11
#> Hornet 4 Drive      21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1    11
```

Another option would be to use `dplyr::across` like so:

```
mtcars |> 
  mutate(total = rowSums(across(!c(hp, mpg, disp, drat, wt, qsec))))
#>                      mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb total
#> Mazda RX4           21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4    15
#> Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4    15
#> Datsun 710          22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1    11
#> Hornet 4 Drive      21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1    11
```

Comment: I think this will work but the NA's are causing a problem do you know how to get R to read them as 0

Comment: You could do `rowSums(..., na.rm = TRUE)`.

Comment: is this in with the rest of the code? if so where about. sorry I'm quite new to this

Comment: Sorry. Using the mtcars example with the across option: `mtcars |> mutate(total = rowSums(across(!c(hp, mpg, disp, drat, wt, qsec)), na.rm = TRUE))`

Comment: Thanks I've tried that but still getting an error saying X must be numeric. All the columns I am using contain numeric data

Comment: Hm. Obviously this is not the case. :D Check your data using e.g. `str(Flower)`to see if all vars are indeed `num`erics or `int`egers. Sometimes columns look numeric but are still characters.

Comment: This comes back saying all of the columns I have used are integer. Do you know if it could be anything else I'm really stumped.

Comment: Hm. Hard to figure out. Could you post the code you tried? Maybe it's just a simple typo or ...

Comment: I've added the updated code onto the original question  thanks for all your help